# Type of data in a trace of type sip

Tags: sip, wireshark, lte

I don´t know the type of data of this trace, and i need to know what happen throughout the communication, i have find some errors like 401 Unhauthorized .

I open Wireshark to see the trace and i obtain this information:

[image: IMAGEN1]
[image: IMAGEN2]

anyone can help me? I don't know a lot of about LTE and sip protocol.

The question is the following:

```
a) What kind of traffic does the trace contain, what is happening?
```